# Bergman space norm in terms of coefficients

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, bergman-spaces

I am interested in the Bergman space $A^2$ on the unit disc. According to the Wikipedia article on [Bergman spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bergman_space), if we have $f(z)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n \in A^2$ then
$$\|f\|^2_{A^2} := \frac{1}{\pi} \int_\mathbb{D} |f(z)|^2 \, dz = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{|a_n|^2}{n+1}$$

I can't prove this (last) equality. I'm trying to construct an isometry from this space to the $l^2$ space but I'm running into trouble with double integrals and (infinite) summation.

I also want to prove the part about the reproducing kernel written later in the Wikipedia article, but I believe it will be easier once I set up the isometry above.

Can anyone help me out please? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functions $\{z^n\}$  $L^2(\mathbb{D})$ are mutually orthogonal in $L^2(\mathbb{D})$, because
$
\int_{\mathbb{D}} z^n \overline z^m =0
$ (integrate in polar coordinates with $r\,d\theta\,dr$, over $\theta$ first).

Also, the integral of $|z^n|^2$ over $\mathbb{D}$ is $\dfrac{2\pi }{2n+2}$, by a similar computation. Hence, 
$$\|f(z)\|^2_{L^2} =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|^2 \|z^n\|^2_{L^2} 
= \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|^2  \frac{2\pi }{2n+2}$$
as claimed.